# Unable to render partial view inside the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using C3CardKYC1.Models;

namespace C3CardKYC1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeControllerController : Controller
    {
        private ConnectionString db = new ConnectionString();

        //
        // GET: /HomeController/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.DetailsEntries.ToList());
        }



        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /HomeController/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(DetailsEntry detailsentry)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.DetailsEntries.Add(detailsentry);
                db.SaveChanges();
                //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(detailsentry);
        }
       [HttpGet]
      public ActionResult displaydocument()
        {
            ViewBag.doctype = new SelectList(db.DocTypeMasters,"Id","DocTypeName");

            return PartialView();
           // return PartialView();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my create view code.

```
@model C3CardKYC1.Models.DetailsEntry

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>DetailsEntry</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpCitizenId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpCitizenId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpCitizenId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nationality)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nationality)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nationality)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentType)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DocumentType)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DocumentType)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@Html.Partial("displaydocument",Model)
```

this is my displaydocument view code

```
@model C3CardKYC1.Models.DocTypeMaster

Select Document Type: @Html.DropDownList("DocTypeName", "Select");
```

I want to generate one view create.cshtl. Inside that i want to render displaydocumentview. I am getting this error. information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'DocTypeName'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should define `DocTypeName` in the `ViewBag` before leaving controller action method.

```
ViewBag.DocTypeName = List<SelectListItem>()
{new SelectListItem("item1", 1), new SelectListItem("item2", 2)};
```

Comment: Where i should make changes?

Comment: Because you tell computer `@Html.DropDownList("DocTypeName", "Select")` so it needs the `DocTypeName` to populate the drop down list from.

Comment: now below error is cmgThe ViewData item that has the key 'DocTypeName' is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: Yes i want to populate dropdownbox

Comment: Then replace `new List<int>()` with your own `List<SelectListItem>` you want to populate from

Comment: ViewBag.DocTypeName = new List<SelectListItem>();
            ViewBag.doctype = new SelectList(db.DocTypeMasters, "Id", "DocTypeName");

Comment: ViewBag.doc = db.DocTypeMasters.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.DocTypeName });

Comment: i wrote above code and nw working fine and view as  @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.DocTypeName1, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.doc)
          . thank its working fine now.